# Why do the windows of my Outlook mail items become unusable after my application terminates?

Tags: vb6, outlook, outlook-redemption

I have a VB6 application which creates and displays mail items in Outlook using Redemption's RDO. Everything works except after my application terminates **the window of every mail item originally created and displayed by my application becomes unusable**, i.e. I cannot send, save or print from that window.

**Requested clarification:** I create the items using `GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDrafts).Items.Add` and display them calling the `Display` method after I attached a file. The user has to send the item explicitly.

Depending on the action I get different generic messages, like "could not send mail" or "the messaging interface returned an unknown error".

I'm really desperate because I've run out of ideas.

What I've tried:

- Different logon methods: `Logon` and `MAPIOBJECT`
- Skipping `Logoff`
- Using `GetObject` instead of `CreateObject` (for the Outlook instance)
- Updating to the latest Redemption version

Some more information:

- The problem exists with Outlook 2007, but the same application works fine with Outlook 2000.
- The item is correctly saved, i.e. if I re-open it using Outlook everything works
- If I use plain Outlook objects everything works fine, too, so it must be something I'm doing wrong with Redemption.

**EDIT:** I downloaded [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) and after my window becomes unusable, every non-trivial action returns the error code 0x800706BA (`RPC_S_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE`). I assume that somehow the connection to the Exchange server is closed for that specific mail item.

- Is that possible?
- Is there anything I can do to prevent that from happending?

**More observations:**

- If I keep my application in memory, opening the same mail item from Outlook opens a new window. Normally the original window would be just brought into the foreground.
- Using Outlook 2000 the window I display does **not** have the additional OutlookSpy buttons.

**EDIT 2009-11-17:** If anyone has some more suggestions I'm still interested!

Answer (score 0):

"creates and displays" is a little vague. Are you creating mail messages and putting them in the outbox? Are you actually sending the messages?

- I would make sure you are on the
  latest version of redemption. They
  have interesting relatively silent
  updates.
- I would try connecting directly to
  the MSFT APIs, disabling redemption,
  to see if that is the cause of your
  issues.
- I would try talking to the folks that
  build redemption to see if they have
  encountered the error.

Outlook crashing is not a big deal. Or, rather, it is a big deal but is relatively common. Not being able to handle mail is pretty darn annoying. I have run into messages that are locked before. On some cases, I have had to move them away from the outbox into some other folder and then move them back. Sometimes that is enough to get them to go out.

Comment: Updating to the latest Redemption version did not solve the problem.